# Finding all dependencies in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
       Parent   Child1  Child2  Child3  Child4  Child5  Child6
0         A       A1      B2      -1     -1       -1     -1
1         B       B1      -1      -1     -1       -1     -1
2         A1      -1      -1      C1     -1       -1     C2
3         D       -1      C2      -1     A1       -1     -1
4         C1      -1      -1      -1     -1       -1     -1
5         C2      -1      -1      -1     -1       -1     -1
6         B1      -1      -1      -1     -1       -1     -1
7         B2      B3      B4      -1     -1       -1     -1
8         B3      -1      -1      -1     -1       -1     -1
9         B4      -1      -1      -1     -1       -1     -1
```

Source:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['A','B','A1','D','C1','C2','B1','B2','B3','B4'],'Child1': ['A1','B1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','B3','-1','-1'], 'Child2': ['B2','-1','-1','C2','-1','-1','-1','B4','-1','-1'] , 'Child3' : ['-1','-1','C1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1'] , 'Child4' : ['-1','-1','-1','A1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1'],'Child5' : ['-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1'] ,'Child6' : ['-1','-1','C2','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1']})
```

Now, I have an input list with a couple of parents like `parent_list = ['A', 'B']`. I need to find all the children of all these parents.
So for 'A', there are two children: A1 and B2. A1 again has two children 'C1' and 'C2'. But 'C1' and 'C2' are childless (if all children are '-1' they are childless) and moving on B2 has two children - 'B3' and 'B4'. Both B3 and B4 are childless, and moving on B has only one child: 'B1' and 'B1' is childless.

So the final family list for `['A', 'B']` is going to be `['A', 'B', 'A1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B1']`

Here is how far I was able to come:

```
parent_list= ['A','B']
tmp_list = []
output_list = []
child_list= []

for i in parent_list:
  output_list.append(i) if i not in output_list else output_list 
  parent_list.remove(i)
  tmp_list = df.loc[df['Parent']  == i, ['Child1','Child2','Child3','Child4','Child5','Child6']].values.flatten().tolist()
  while '-1' in tmp_list: tmp_list.remove('-1')
  if  tmp_list:
    parent_list = parent_list + tmp_list
```

However, my code only runs for `i = 'A'` in the parent_list and stops. I Am not sure why it wouldn't iterate any further. when I check parent_list  after the frist iteration I do see what I want to see but looping doesnt happen. Where am I doing wrong?

Also if there's any better ways of approaching this problem, please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

We can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe, then create a *directed graph* with the help of `networkx` then use [`descendents`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html) method to find all the children for each parent node in the `parent_list`

```
import networkx as nx

s = df.melt('Parent').astype(str).query("value != '-1'")
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(s, 'Parent', 'value', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
family = parent_list + [d for n in parent_list for d in nx.descendants(G, n)]
```

---

```
>>> family

['A', 'B', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B2', 'B4', 'A1', 'B1']
```

Answer (score 1):

So the reason why the for loop only runs for A is because you're trying to edit the `parent_list` while you're iterating through it. So the iterator is on 'A', which you then remove, so it is then on 'B', and then at the end of the block it iterates again and that's the end of the list. This is combined with the fact that you are reassigning the value of `parent_list` by using `parent_list = parent_list + tmp_list`. As a result the loop iterator is looking at the old `parent_list` which just has 'B' in it now, while your variable is looking at a new `parent_list` that has B and A's children.

The simplest solution in your case seems to be just removing the line `parent_list.remove(i)` as it doesn't seem necessary and is causing this problem. Also you will need to change the `+` to `+=` or `.extend()` so that it updates the original list that you are iterating through. This seemed to work when I tried it.

I personally think a better solution would be to use a recursive function to get the children. Something like:

```
def get_children(parent):
    child_list = df.loc[df['Parent']  == parent, ['Child1','Child2','Child3','Child4','Child5','Child6']].values.flatten().tolist()
    while '-1' in child_list: child_list.remove('-1')
    for i in child_list:
        child_list.extend(get_children(i))
    # cast to set and back to remove duplicate children
    return list(set(child_list))
```

I tested this and it more or less achieves what you want for a single parent. If you want the whole family you can just iterate through your parent_list using this function and then combine the parent_list with the returned lists

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. So If I understand you correctly ; you are saying I can't alter the list while iterating through it . lets take a very simple example : 
**
my_try = ['a','b']
for i in my_try :
  if i == 'a':
   my_try.append('c')
  if i == 'c':
   print('Him')
**
    I see 'Him' in the output which means I am able to modify the list while iterating through it right?

Comment: It's not that you can't alter the list, it's just that you did it incorrectly. The two main issues I outlined above are that you are deleting an entry while iterating without handling it (which caused you to skip over B) and you are re-assigning the list variable you are iterating through (which meant that the iterator did not see the added items from tmp_list. These problems do not occur in your example because you are adding an entry and did so using append.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explantion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import copy
df.set_index('Parent', inplace=True)
df.replace('-1', np.nan, inplace=True)
parent_list = ['A','B']
family = copy.deepcopy(parent_list)
for p in family:
    family.extend(df.loc[p].dropna().to_list())
```

OUTPUT:

```
['A', 'B', 'A1', 'B2', 'B1', 'C1', 'C2', 'B3', 'B4']
```